# Char validation c++

Tags: c++

trying to get a function to work however I'm still pretty beginner at coding - this function is clearing all my inputs as valid however, as I understand it, it should be failing them?

```
char input;
bool valid;

do
{
    valid = false;
    gotoXY(col, row);
    cin >> input;

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        message("Invalid input! Please re-enter.", 5, offset);
        cin.clear();
        clearLine(col, row);
        clearLine(0, row + 2);
    }
    else
    {
        valid = true;

    }

    cin.ignore(150, '\n');

    clearLine2(5, offset);
    clearLine2(5, offset + 2);

} while (!valid);

cin.setf(ios::skipws);

return input;
```

I simply can't find a solution for this and it's really causing some headaches, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you expect your code to do?  And what is it doing that is not expected?

Comment: say if i input 1 or a string it should result in a failure message however this just accepts everything

Comment: You need to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @j.m Why should it fail if you enter `1`?  That is a valid character.

Comment: That is not a function. It's a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to the cin to fail in case you entered "1 or  a string"

but the failure cases for cin could be the entered value doesn't fit in the variable.

Reference,
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/2957/
[Meaning of cin.fail() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906990/meaning-of-cin-fail-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see Your code says:
If Your input will fail (nothing goes to input) then send msg.
else accept everything.
For me it looks like You have to swap them.